# How to fix executing gnuradio-companion without sudo

Tags: python, linux, sudo, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I want to run the application "gnuradio-companion".  I can do this without problems by executing sudo gnuradio-companion.  But I do not want to run this with sudo.  If I try to run without sudo I get the following.  Can you help please?

```
lenovo@Lenovo-ThinkPad-T440:~$ gnuradio-companion 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnuradio-companion", line 112, in <module>
    run_main()
  File "/usr/bin/gnuradio-companion", line 105, in run_main
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/main.py", line 83, in main
    platform.build_library()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/core/platform.py", line 197, in build_library
    utils.hide_bokeh_gui_options_if_not_installed(self.blocks['options'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py", line 898, in __getitem__
    return self.__missing__(key)            # support subclasses that define __missing__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py", line 890, in __missing__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'options'
```

Comment: hey, what versionof GNU Radio is this, and how did you install it?

Comment: GNU Radio version 3.8.5.0 (Python 3.8.10)  installed on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with sudo apt install gnuradio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>    raise KeyError(key)
> KeyError: 'options'
> ```

This error indicates that `gnuradio-companion` can't find `options.block.yml` for some reasons.

First make sure that you do have this file in `/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/` directory and then check what blocks paths are configured in your user's gnuradio config

```
$ grep -R blocks_path $HOME/.gnuradio $HOME/.grc_gnuradio/
```

If you have `global_blocks_path` variable set but it does not contains the directory where the `options.block.yml` file is then you can add it or comment out (remove) `global_blocks_path`

In case that you don't have some custom configs you can try removing the `$HOME/.gnuradio` and `$HOME/.grc_gnuradio` directories as well.

Comment: Thank you Vasil.  That solved it!  My global_blocks_path was pointing to an incorrect directory - I have no idea why though!   Thanks again.